# Why am I unable to console.log() anything in react?

Tags: reactjs, browser

```js
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Hello');
    return ( 
      <div> App component </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am facing this issue since yesterday. `Hello` should have been printed in the console on inspecting my website but nothing is getting displayed. I saved the code and also refreshed the browser.

[image]

Comment: please share "index.js" and "package.json" of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Open your browser inspection and select the `console` tab on it. Click on the `All levels` and make sure all the options are selected:

[image: inspect browser]